# How to Move Resource group in AZURE from 1 subscription (1 tenant id ) to another subscription ( another tenant ID)

Tags: azure

How to Move Resource group from 1 subscription (1 tenant id ) to another subscription ( another tenant ID)
It is easy to move from 1 subscription to another in the same tenant ID . but what about another tenant id

Regards 
Ash

Comment: I don't want to move whole subscription --- I just want to move 1 Resource Group and its resources from a subscription to another subscription in another tenant . SO i have subscription A -- which has Resource Group A . Now i create a New subscription - with a new teanant ID . . I want to move Resource Group A from Subscription A - to the New Subscription which has a New Tenant ID.

Answer (score 1):

Check article here: 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51360.azure-how-to-move-resources-between-subscriptions-under-different-tenants.aspx

On moving resource groups between subscriptions:

> You can move a VM and its associated resources to a different
>   subscription by using the Azure portal. Click Browse > Resource groups
>   and select the resource group containing the VM that you would like to
>   move. At the top of the page for the resource group, select Move and
>   then select Move to another subscription.

Basically you need to create a temporary subscription on the first tenant and move the subscription to the other.

Check the article here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/leandrowp.blog/2018/09/28/how-to-migrate-subscriptions-from-one-azure-ad-tenant-to-another/amp/

Then move the resource to the other subscription and delete the temporary one.

Beware that RBAC security will not be migrated

Answer (score 0):

If you can move all the resources in subscription to second tenant. Please follow this,
https://www.wesleyhaakman.org/transferring-ea-subscriptions-to-csp/